# Getting [NSRecursiveLock dealloc]: lock with UITextView

Tags: ios, gdb, uitextview, breakpoints

I have an app with a UITableView and a detail view (classic).
My detail view contains a UITextView and some UILabels.

Each time I open the detail view more than once, I get this error:

```
*** -[NSRecursiveLock dealloc]: lock (<NSRecursiveLock: 0x15632fc0> '(null)') deallocated while still in use
*** Break on _NSLockError() to debug.
```

If I remove the UITextView, or use a UILabel instead, I don't have the error anymore.
The UITextView is an IBOutlet that is set in the ViewDidLoad like this:

```
[self.textView setText:objectToPrint.title];
```

I also tried to set a break point on _NSLockError but I don't understand the result:

```
Foundation`_NSLockError:
0x30fcf058:  push   {r7, lr}
0x30fcf05a:  movw   r0, #4512
0x30fcf05e:  mov    r7, sp
0x30fcf060:  movt   r0, #2534
0x30fcf064:  add    r0, pc
0x30fcf066:  bl     0x30f696d0                ; NSLog
0x30fcf06a:  pop    {r7, pc}
```

Does someone have any idea on how I can solve this problem?

Comment: I see this too when resetting a frame for UITextView

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I don't reset the frame of the UITextView, all I do is setting the delegate and the text in the ViewDidLoad method. `self.comicsTitle.delegate = self;
    [self.comicsTitle setText:comicsToPrint.title];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the same controllers for the iPad UI without any error.
So I suspect that I have a problem due to iOS 7 beta version ...

EDIT

Indeed, my problem disappear with the last version of the iOS 7 beta.